# Google Pay for Passes Postman Oauth2 access token

Tags: rest, postman, google-pay

How to correctly configure Postman to obtain the Oauth2 access token for testing the Google Pay for Passes REST API?

I followed the [getting started](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/basic-setup/get-access-to-rest-api) guide carefully, but, after setting the Postman Oauth2 dialog (with callbackurl, auth url, access token url, client id, client secret and scope) and choosing the right account, I occur in a page with this error:

> Error 400: invalid_scope
>   Some requested scopes cannot be shown: 
>   [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer]
>   Request details
>   response_type=code
>   client_id=[REMOVED]
>   redirect_uri=https://www.getpostman.com/o/oauth2/callback
>   access_type=online
>   display=page
>   scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer

The same error occurs with the Google API Playground.

Comment: Did you solve that error ? If yes, how did you do ? Thanks for answer !

Comment: see the accepted answer, that solved my problem at the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the service account credential as per https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#Overview. There you will see libraries used and samples to handle the authentication and that is the recommended way.